# Using Market Prices of Bonds to Model the Discount Curve with a Polynomial (Math + R)

Tags: fixed-income, r, optimization, interpolation

I have a small program I'm building to interpolate the discount curve from a portfolio of benchmark bonds. If anyone has any guesses as to whether it's my process, or my code that's messed up I would greatly appreciate it.

The math behind it is for the most part straight forward compared to most interest rate models:

The market price of a bond is the discounted value of its cash flows:

```
MPj = Cj1*D1 + Cj2*D2 +… + Cji*Di + Error
Where
MPj = Cash price of bond j 
Cji = ith cash flow for bond j
Di = Discount factor for the ith cash flow
```

Use a polynomial to model the discount factor:

```
Di = B0 + B1*Ti  + B2*Ti^2 + … + Bk*Ti^k
Where:    
Di = Discount factor at time = i 
k = The degree of the polynomial
Ti = Time until the ith cash flow, in years 
Bk = The coefficients of the model which describe how the time to cash flow determines the discount factor
```

Substitute the second equation into the first:

```
MPj = Cj1 [B0 + B1*T1 + B2*T12 + … + Bk*T1k] +… + Cji [B0 + B1*Ti + B2*Ti2 + … + Bk*Tik ] + Error
```

and in matrix form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mLJ6.png

From there, take the squared error of this equation, and minimize it by changing the coefficients.

Does this process make sense?

When I try to implement it, I end up with very large squared errors (~73.5 over 15 bonds).

This is the data I'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zeg5xyt5kq4xcpm/Sample%20Data.csv?dl=0

This is the code I'm using. Any comments are appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Polynomial_Degree = 3
Start_Date <- as.Date(ymd(19990122))
Face_Value <- 100
Default_Coeffs_Guess <- rep(0,Polynomial_Degree + 1)

Databank <- read.csv(paste(getwd(), "Sample Data.csv", sep="/"), stringsAsFactors = F)

Coupon_Values_List <- Databank %>%
  select(COUPON) %>%
  data.frame %>%
  rename(.,Coupon_Values_List = COUPON)

Coupon_Values_List2 <- Databank %>%
  select(COUPON) %>%
  transmute(., Coupon_Values_List2 = COUPON +1) %>%
  data.frame

Maturity_Date_List <- Databank %>% 
  select(MATURITY) %>% 
  lapply(mdy) %>%
  lapply(as.Date) %>%
  data.frame

Bond_Midpricing <- Databank %>%
  transmute(., Bond_Midpricing = (BID.PRICE+ASK.PRICE)/2) %>%
  as.matrix

#Functions 1:
Coupon_Count_Function <- function(Maturity_Date, Coupon_Payment_Frequency){

  Coupon_Count <- 0
  Coupon_Count <- as.double(ceiling(((as.Date(Maturity_Date)-as.Date(Start_Date))*Coupon_Payment_Frequency)/365)-1)

  return(Coupon_Count)
}

#Function 2: 
Coupon_Dates_Function <- function(Maturity_Date, Coupon_Payment_Frequency){

  Coupon_Payment_Dates <- NULL
  Coupon_Count=Coupon_Count_Function(Maturity_Date,2)

  for (i in 0:Coupon_Count) 
  {x <- as.numeric(((as.Date(as.Date(Maturity_Date)-i*365/Coupon_Payment_Frequency))-Start_Date)/365)
  Coupon_Payment_Dates <- rbind(Coupon_Payment_Dates, data.frame(x))}

  return((Coupon_Payment_Dates))
}

#Function 3:
Coupon_Time_Func <- function(Maturity_Dates, Coupon_Payment_Frequency) {

  All_Coupon_Time_List <- apply(Maturity_Dates, 1, Coupon_Dates_Function, Coupon_Payment_Frequency = 2)

  return(All_Coupon_Time_List)
}


#Function 4:
Independent_Variable_Matrix_Func <- function(Maturity_Date_List, Coupon_Payment_Frequency, Coupon_Values_List, 
                                             Polynomial_Degree){

  df <- data.frame(I(Coupon_Time_Func(Maturity_Date_List, Coupon_Payment_Frequency)),Coupon_Values_List)
  names(df) <- c("All_Coupon_Time_List", "Coupon_Values_List")

  Temp_List <- vector(mode = "list", Polynomial_Degree+1)
  for (i in 1:(Polynomial_Degree+1)) {

    Summation_Column_Coupons <- NULL
    Summation_Column_Coupons <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {y* sum(x^(i-1))}, df$All_Coupon_Time_List, 
                                       df$Coupon_Values_List)

    Summation_Column_With_Principle <- NULL
    Summation_Column_With_Principle <- mapply(Summation_Column_Coupons, df$All_Coupon_Time_List, Face_Value, 
                                              FUN = function(x,y,z) {x+max(y^(i-1))*z})

    Temp_List[[i]] <- Summation_Column_With_Principle
  }

  Independent_Variable_Matrix <- NULL
  Independent_Variable_Matrix <- as.matrix(t(rbind(Independent_Variable_Matrix, do.call(rbind, Temp_List))))
  return(Independent_Variable_Matrix)
}

Independent_Variable_Matrix <- Independent_Variable_Matrix_Func(Maturity_Date_List, Coupon_Payment_Frequency, Coupon_Values_List, 
                                                                Polynomial_Degree)

#Function 5:
Sum_Error_Squared_Func <- function(Coeffs){

Estimated_Prices_Vector <-  Independent_Variable_Matrix %*% Coeffs

Sum_Error_Squared <- sum((Bond_Midpricing - Estimated_Prices_Vector)^2)

return(Sum_Error_Squared)
}

optim (par = Default_Coeffs_Guess,
       fn = Sum_Error_Squared_Func,
       gr = NULL,
       method  = "L-BFGS-B",
       lower   = c(-1000,-1000,-1000,-1000),
       upper   = c(1000,1000,1000,1000))
```